# Calculate sold units by summing up changes in stock - MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've been trying to solve this for the last 2 days, I'm out of ideas, perhaps somebody here will be able to help me. I want to calculate total units sold based on **stock_history** array. I sorted this array from the oldest entry and then used **$reduce** to go through every element, however I don't know how to keep track of the previous element to compare them.

I'd only count units as sold if the stock decreased (i.e from 104 to 74).

My document looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "70556",
  "name": "Sample Product",
  "current_stock": 84,
  "stock_history": [
    {
      "stock": 104,
      "ts": {
        "$date": "2023-04-11T15:58:10.242Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "stock": 104,
      "ts": {
        "$date": "2023-04-11T19:31:47.811Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "stock": 74,
      "ts": {
        "$date": "2023-04-13T18:08:30.244Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "stock": 84,
      "ts": {
        "$date": "2023-04-14T00:00:28.375Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My output should look like this:

```
{
"id": "70556",
"units_sold": 30
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to iterate over the index of the item, using the `$arrayElemAt`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      id: 1,
      _id: 0,
      units_sold: {$reduce: {
          input: {$range: [1, {$size: "$stock_history"}]},
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {$add: [
              "$$value",
              {$max: [
                  {$subtract: [
                      {$arrayElemAt: ["$stock_history.stock", {$subtract: ["$$this", 1]}]},
                      {$arrayElemAt: ["$stock_history.stock", "$$this"]}
                  ]},
                  0
              ]}
          ]}
      }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mcOFfbIJa-j)

Comment: Thank you for your help. That's exactly what I needed, and there is no way I could have come up with that.